# Why is this JSON invalid?

Tags: iphone, json, jsonlint

```
{
    "already_public": "null",
    "status": "true",
    "message": "Service provider added successfully",
    "detail": {
        "id": "1175",
        "address_1": "",
        "address_2": "",
        "profession": "Accountant",
        "city": "",
        "company": "",
        "email_1": "",
        "email_2": "",
        "firstname": "das\' feet",
        "lastname": "",
        "life_block": "Family",
        "work_phone": "",
        "mobile_phone": "",
        "home_phone": "",
        "fax": "",
        "state": "",
        "title": "",
        "website": "",
        "zip": "",
        "ismyprovider": "1",
        "privacy": "null",
        "img_url": "http://localhost/mtube/uploads/blank_pic.png"
    },
    "inresponseto": "addServiceProvider"
}
```

Everything is ok except for this line

```
"firstname": "das\' feet"
```

It has a single quote within double quote. Despite having a `\` before the character this json is being invalidated by jsonlint.

Comment: try escaping the slash with another one? "das\\' feet"

Comment: validate if here [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: My logic says escaping the "\" with "\\" essential says string("das\' feet") - As far is I know jsonlint needs a character after the ' to be escabed - try this maybe "das\'s feet" - I know it's not what you want but it may prove the theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should be double slash to escape slash char

```
"firstname": "das\\' feet"
```

Comment: with double slashes it is working here in browser, but the iphone parser fails to parse :(

Comment: @Sarah, is  `/` required in first name?,  you can also skip `/` from name. **"firstname": "das' feet"**

Comment: What iphone parser are you using ? If it doesnt parse the JSON with `das\\' feet` I think it has a problem you should file to them.

Answer (score 2):

The single quote `'` shouldn't be escaped:

> [image]
>
> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.
>
> [JSON.org](http://json.org/)

As you can see, the single quote shouldn't be escaped.

Or if you want to keep the `\`, than you need to escape that:

```
 "firstname": "das\\' feet",
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to escape single quote. More info is [here](http://www.json.org/)